# Docker build failing after adding shared project

Tags: asp.net, docker, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I'm having some trouble trying to get docker to build my .net core solution after adding a shared project.

My solution looks like this:

```
Solution
   Project1
     Reference to project2
   Project2
     Reference to shared project
```

Adding docker support to the solution yields the expected output in the dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Project1/Project1.csproj", "Project1/"]
COPY ["Project2/Project2.csproj", "Project2/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Project1/Project1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Project1"
RUN dotnet build "Project1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Project1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project1.dll"]
```

Bizarrely, this seems to work find if I launch docker in debug config, but it fails when I try to launch it in release config. The failure is:

```
/src/Project2/Project2.csproj(16,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/SharedProject/SharedProject/SharedProject.projitems" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "../../SharedProject/SharedProject/SharedProject.projitems" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

The shared project files most definitely exist, and they're being used successfully in other solutions that don't rely on Docker.

What am I missing here? Do I need to change the dockerfile in some way to reflect that the shared project files aren't in the same folder structure as this solution?

EDIT: As part of the troubleshooting process, I added a shared project directly to this solution (then copied in all the code from the *actual* shared project which is located elsewhere). Docker seems happy with this and launches in both debug and release mode. So I'm still assuming it's something to do with the original shared project being located outside of the folder structure for this solution, and my not understanding how to get Docker to know where to look for it...

Comment: what is your question here ?

Comment: My questions are:
Can I have a shared project (which resides outside of the folder structure of this project) included in the solution and have Docker build it successfully?
If so, how do I adjust my Dockerfile to achieve this?
If not, how do people create docker-enabled solutions in Visual Studio that use shared projects from outside the solution filesystem?

Comment: just move you docker file outside at solution level and build it. it will work.

Comment: Nope...that doesn't work either. I get the exact same error.
For eg, my shared project is in c:\somefolder\sharedsolution\sharedproject.
The solution I'm trying to have Docker include this in is in c:\adifferentfolder\thissolution\

Comment: in such case, you have to put the dockerfile at higher level folder in the same level as somefolder and adifferentfolder. and then you can include any project you want.